# Update a record using Entity Framework receiving 2 parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to update a specific row of the database. This is the code:

```
public void Update_Datos(int ID)
{
    int UserId = Convert.ToInt16((string)(Session["UserId"]));
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        //Reading
        List<Datos_Personales> objDatos = db.Datos_Personales.ToList<Datos_Personales>();
        foreach (Datos_Personales item in objDatos)
        {

        }
        //Update
        var datos_personales = db.Datos_Personales.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserId == UserId && d.Id == ID);
        Datos_Personales datos = objDatos[datos_personales.Id];
        datos = db.Datos_Personales.Where(d => d.UserId == UserId && d.Id == ID).First();
        datos.Fecha_de_nacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(Fecha_de_nacimiento.Text);
        datos.Nombre_Completo = txt_Nombre_Completo.Text;
        datos.Identificacion = txt_Identificacion.Text;
        datos.Estado_civil = ddEstadoCivil.SelectedValue;
        datos.Telefono = txt_num_telefono.Text;
        datos.Departamento = ddDepartamento.SelectedValue;
        datos.Nacionalidad = Country.SelectedValue;
        datos.Salario_min_aceptado = ddSalario_min_aceptado.SelectedValue;
        datos.Titulo = txt_Titulo.Text;
        datos.Descripcion_Profesional = txt_Descripcion_Profesional.Text;
        datos.UserId = Convert.ToInt16(UserId);
        db.Datos_Personales.Add(datos);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The other is issue is that it creating another row instead updating the one which I need.

Comment: Remove the line _db.Datos_Personales.Add(datos);_ The _datos_ variable is tracked by EF and you just need to save.

Comment: Further to what @Steve said, consider where you got `datos` from in the first place: `datos = db.Datos_Personales.Where(d => d.UserId == UserId && d.Id == ID).First();`. You got it from `db.Datos_Personales` in the first place so why would you need to add it to that same collection? `Add` is for adding new entities, which is why a new record is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not read all Db. When you use this line `List<Datos_Personales> objDatos = db.Datos_Personales.ToList<Datos_Personales>();`, your all entity (all rows in Db) stored into memory.

You can fetch your data directly and edit it. Finally you must not add entity again, only call `SaveChages`. (If you did not close `ChangeTracker`)

```
public void Update_Datos(int ID)
{
    int UserId = Convert.ToInt16((string)(Session["UserId"]));
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        Datos_Personales datos = db.Datos_Personales.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserId == UserId && d.Id == ID));
        if(datos == null)
            return;

        datos.Fecha_de_nacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(Fecha_de_nacimiento.Text);
        datos.Nombre_Completo = txt_Nombre_Completo.Text;
        datos.Identificacion = txt_Identificacion.Text;
        datos.Estado_civil = ddEstadoCivil.SelectedValue;
        datos.Telefono = txt_num_telefono.Text;
        datos.Departamento = ddDepartamento.SelectedValue;
        datos.Nacionalidad = Country.SelectedValue;
        datos.Salario_min_aceptado = ddSalario_min_aceptado.SelectedValue;
        datos.Titulo = txt_Titulo.Text;
        datos.Descripcion_Profesional = txt_Descripcion_Profesional.Text;
        datos.UserId = Convert.ToInt16(UserId);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```